# Installation of El Capitan on Intel Core Duo taking so far 2 days. What can I do?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I am installing OS X El Capitan on a Mid 2009 MacBook Pro. Previously running an OS X 10.8.5. Incidentally my installation is taking now two days. I have tried holding down the power button but still no difference. It resumes where it stopped I feel frustrated and I want to return to my previous operation system. What can I do? Does it mean my machine has crashed? have I lost or can I recover my work? Making matters worse I can't tell what percentage of installation achieved? Apart from the bar that has moved from 0% up to around 75% and it's stagnant at that level. I am confused on what to do.

Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Theres not much you can do if it still says installing after all that, i think the best and safest thing you can do now is book an appointment at the apple store. You could tamper with it and maybe fix it but at this point in my opinion just take in to the store.

Answer (score 0):

***There is an installation problem - 2 days is way to long; 1 day is actually way too long.***

I personally upgraded a colleagues 2009 MBP to El Capitan with no issues.  However, prior to the upgrade, I upgraded it to [8GB of RAM](http://amzn.to/1UkNzLw) and added a [Samsung SSD](http://amzn.to/1RUwTsk) (solid state drive).  The links I provided were for the exact products that I used.  Installation of El Capitan took around an hour total (I didn't hang around to watch/time it)

The reason for the upgrade was that the original TSM (traditional spinning media) HDD that came with it was dying.  Booting started taking up to 10 minutes and browsing the web became unbarable.  You might be experiencing that same problem.  Use [DriveDX](http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) (free option) to determine if drive is failing (which is what I am suspecting).

As always, make sure you do a Time Machine backup of your drive before the upgrade.  However, (IMO) just migrate over your data.  Do a nice clean installation of El Capitan and all the applications you have - it's been my experience that computers are much more stable when doing clean installs rather than in-place upgrades and/or backup/restore of apps.